# Power Series with digits of $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series, pi

Sorry if this has already been asked, but I haven't found a post.
Can anything be said about the function
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$$
where the $a_n$'s are the digits of $\pi= 3.14159...$, so $$a_0=3,a_1=1,a_2=4,a_3=1,...$$ and so on. Since the coefficients are pretty random, the behaviour of the function is hard to predict. Bounding $|f(z)|\leq9\sum_{n=0}^\infty |z|^n$, it is seen that the radius of convergence is $1$, but what exactly happens at the boundary? Is it even extendible to outside of the unit-disc or are there infinitely many singularities?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Well no, but just because a series converges at 1 point, doesn't mean it is extendible.  You need an open environment, or?

Comment: I mean $\sum_{n} z^n$ does converge on $|z|=1$ except at $z=1$, so it depends on the choice of $a_n$.

Comment: Ah, ok... maybe we missunderstand. The thing I'm really interested in is if it is extendible as in the geometric series or other functions. Why is $|z|=1$ the natural boundary?

Comment: I mean for example if the coeffiencts $a_n$ are periodic with period $N$, then the numbers on the unit circle $z_k=e^{i 2\pi k/N}$ for $k=0...N-1$ are singularities of $f$, since $$f(z_k)=\sum_{l=0}^{N-1} \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_{l+jN} e^{i2\pi k/N \cdot (l+jN)} = \sum_{l=0}^{N-1} a_l e^{i2\pi kl/N} \sum_{j=0}^\infty 1 = \infty$$ except if $$\sum_{l=0}^{N-1} a_l z_k^l=0 \, .$$

Comment: By definition, $f(\frac{1}{10}) = \pi.$

Comment: Look up Polya-Carlson theorem on power series with integral coefficients and radius $1$- they are either rational or the unit disc is natural boundary

Comment: It's an interesting result because of the radius $1$ condition (for example $(1-4z)^{-1/2}$ is algebraic so extendable everyone except at $1/4$ and the infinity and not rational with integral coefficients but radius is $1/4$ not $1$